# Auto-create list and append element

Tags: python

In PHP, you can simplify the inside of the loop:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($dataset as $dataElement){
    if (isset($result[$dataElement->date])
        array_push($result[$dataElement->date], $dataElement);
    else
        $result[$dataElement->date] = $dataElement;
}
```

to:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($dataset as $dataElement){
    $result[$dataElement->date][] = $dataElement;
}
```

Which basically appends the data element to the sub-array while creating it on the fly if it doesn't exist.

Is it possible to have a simple one-liner like such in Python? Seems like I need the array to exist then call the `List.append()` method absolutely.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is called `list comprehension`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be what you're looking for:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for element in dataset:
   result[element.date].append(element)
```

If the `result` dictionary doesn't contain an `element.date` entry a new `list` is created, otherwise the existing list is used and in either case the `element` is appended.

Comment: Works perfectly and easy enough to understand thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension to do this in one line

So this:

```
dat = []
for val in range(1,10):
     dat.append(val)
```

Becomes this Using List Comprehension:

```
dat = [val for val in range(1,10) if val (some condition)]
```

Comment: cheers, I didn't know how to add condition to list comprehension. +1

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to emulate desired behaviour by subclassing collections.UserDict class

```
from collections import UserDict

class AutoDict(UserDict):
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        if name not in self.data:
            self.data[name] = []
        return self.data[name]

l = AutoDict()
print('before', l)
l['some val'].append(2)
print('after', l)
```

Comment: You could just subclass `dict` directly, `UserDict` is a hangover from the early days of Python before you could subclass the builtins. Also it's better to override `__missing__` as that only gets called if the key isn't in the dictionary so you can just return a new list and not have to handle the `__getitem__` stuff at all. But `collections.defaultdict` already does all of that for you.

Comment: For this particular example, yes, sub-classing dict or implementing __missing__ does the job, but as docs say "... this class can be easier to work with
because the underlying dictionary is accessible as an attribute", so one might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to fulfill more than 1 condition. You can also stack more `if` `else if` `else` in your list comprehension. See below for example.

```
a_list = ['twos' if var%2==0 else 'threes' if var%3==0 else var for var in range(0,10)]
a_list
>>> ['twos', 1, 'twos', 'threes', 'twos', 5, 'twos', 7, 'twos', 'threes']
```